# Dropdown navigation list

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around trying to get a dropdown navigation list to display how i would like. I have managed to get it to display on hover which is what i want but what i am trying to do is have the nested hover dropdown appear in the center underneath its parent link with a nice bit of padding either side. Hope that makes sense, i have put a jsfiddle up to show you how it looks at the moment.

https://jsfiddle.net/guueLvq3/

```css
.main-nav {
  background: #718373;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5%;
  padding: 2%;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #718373;
}

nav ul ul li {
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.row:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-nav">
   <div class="row">
     <nav>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">About</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Diary</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` elements have default `padding-left` (or `margin-left`) property sets on it. You have to clear that property first, then set a padding on the `li` element as you wish.

If you want your submenu in `absolute` position `relative` to the parent `li`, be careful about `left` and `right` values to center it.

> Css modified :

```
nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #718373;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  left: 0; right: 0; 
}

nav ul ul li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10hvaebb/2/)

Comment: Many thanks for that, just what i was looking for really appreciate it. One last thing with this though, i have added a border to the drop down menu on hover but it seems to want to show outside of the menu. I have updated the fiddle to show you what i mean if thats ok https://jsfiddle.net/10hvaebb/4/

Comment: You're welcome, should be good like that : https://jsfiddle.net/10hvaebb/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

i found this in http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp.
Hope it is useful for you.